# What kind of string is produced by successive application of argmax M

Tags: computability, randomness

Fix a version of Solomonoff's universal distribution $\mathbf M$ and consider the following procedure for generating an infinite binary sequence $\omega$.

Start with some $\omega_0$. Each subsequent element is given by $\omega_n=\arg \max_a\mathbf M(a|\omega_{1:n-1})$.

What are the properties of $\omega$? For example, is it necessarily computable? Does the answer depend on the choice of $\mathbf M$?

**UPDATE**

The equivalent formulation is the following but it does not really help me advance with the problem.

Is there a universal lower semicomputable $\lambda$-supermartingale $t$ and a binary sequence $\tilde\omega$ such that $t$ always "goes up" along $\tilde\omega$ but never succeeds?

This type of problem arises when a player plays against a reactive environment and the sequence the player observes is not exogenous. A more general question is what is the short-run behavior of $\mathbf M$ since asymptotic results do not seem to help here.

Comment: Would ties be broken in favor of zero? $\;$

Comment: Yes, for example, ties are be broken in favor of zero.

Answer (score 0):

It is computable.

Although $M$ is incomputable, since $M(x)\sim 2^{-K(x)}$, the sequence $\omega$ generated by $argmax M$ would have quite low Kolmogorov complexity.

If the sequence is generated by $argmin M$, then it would be Martin-lof random.